# How to embed JPanel into JavaFX pane for graph visualization

Tags: java, javafx, jpanel, jung

How can I add a swingNode to a specific pane using my controller class?

I'm trying to add a JPanel that loads a network graph created using the JUNG software library I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want to do using [SwingNode](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) class. Here is an example code where a JButton (swing component) is added to a StackPane (JavaFX component):

```
 public class SwingFx extends Application {

     @Override
     public void start(Stage stage) {
         final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
         createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);

         StackPane pane = new StackPane();
         pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

         stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 100, 50));
         stage.show();
     }

     private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 swingNode.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"));
             }
         });
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
     }
 }
```

Source: http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html